# My JavaScript function is not working in my html

Tags: javascript, html, django, cs50

I am trying to run a function called send mail but it doesn't run at all because the response is supposed to be 201 when it runs but django returns a 200 response like it isn't there. I tried running the function directly in my console and it worked fine so the backend is working as excpected.
Here is the JS code:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit',send_mail);

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';

}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
    // Print emails
      console.log(emails);

    // ... do something else with emails ...
  });
}


function send_mail(){
    fetch('/emails/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          recipients: document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value,
          subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
          body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
        console.log(result);
    });

}
```

Here is the HTML

```
    {% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here the Documentation for the django API:

To send an email, you can send a POST request to the /emails route. The route requires three pieces of data to be submitted: a recipients value (a comma-separated string of all users to send an email to), a subject string, and a body string. For example, you could write JavaScript code like

```
fetch('/emails', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'baz@example.com',
      subject: 'Meeting time',
      body: 'How about we meet tomorrow at 3pm?'
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    // Print result
    console.log(result);
});
```

If the email is sent successfully, the route will respond with a 201 status code and a JSON response of {"message": "Email sent successfully."}.

Comment: Make your buttons buttons and not submit buttons and see if it helps. `<button type="button" />`

Comment: that didn't work either

Comment: Let me guess. Hitting submit will reload the page? Thats the default behavior. you have to prfent the default event (event.preventDefault); inside of your submit function. Do not forget to use event as an function param. More here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp